# How to compare datetime object effectively

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have a dictionary with around 15k records which is formatted like this:

```
sample = {0: {'Schedule': ['2017-05-11', '2019-04-30', '2018-10-13', '2019-05-31', '', '']},
      1: {'Schedule': ['2017-05-09', '2019-05-31', '', '', '2018-10-13', '2019-05-31']},
      2: {'Schedule': ['2017-05-02', '2020-02-29', '', '', '2018-10-12', '2020-02-29']}}
```

Now i have to compare the 1st, 3rd and 5th dates in `'Schedule'` with two datetime objects and see if falls within the range. I am doing the below, but the result is quite slow and takes like 20 seconds. Can anyone suggest a more efficient way of searching?

Full sample code:

```
from datetime import datetime

sample = {0: {'Schedule': ['2017-05-11', '2019-04-30', '2018-10-13', '2019-05-31', '', '']},
          1: {'Schedule': ['2017-05-09', '2019-05-31', '', '', '2018-10-13', '2019-05-31']},
          2: {'Schedule': ['2017-05-02', '2020-02-29', '', '', '2018-10-12', '2020-02-29']}}

start_date = datetime.date(datetime.strptime("2018-10-12","%Y-%m-%d"))
end_date = datetime.date(datetime.strptime("2018-10-16","%Y-%m-%d"))

for k,v in sample.items():
    earliest = [dt for dt in [v["Schedule"][0],v["Schedule"][2],v["Schedule"][4]] if dt] #only need to check these 3 starting dates
    def check_earliest(_list):  #check if any date meets search criteria
        for i in _list:
            if start_date <= datetime.date(datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d")) <= end_date:
                return True
    if check_earliest(earliest):
        print ("Do something here...")
```

Comment: Parsing the datetime objects with `datetime.date` is already one huge bottleneck. The date strings are already in ISO 8601 format, so you don't need to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use datetime objects, *or* start with `datetime` objects in your dictionary so you don't have to convert them just for this comparison.

You don't have to use `datetime` objects because your dates are in YYYY-MM-DD order, the [ISO 8601 definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Such dates, as strings, are *lexicographically* comparable in the correct order for dates.

So

```
start_date = "2018-10-12"
end_date = "2018-10-16"

for k,v in sample.items():
    sched = v['Schedule']
    earliest = [dt for dt in (sched[0], sched[2], sched[4]) if dt]
    def check_earliest(l):
        for i in l:
            if start_date <= i <= end_date:
                return True
    if check_earliest(earliest):
        print("Do something here...")
```

works just fine already.

I'd use the `any()` function here to test your dates, rather than define your own function:

```
for k, v in sample.items():
    sched = v['Schedule']
    if any(sched[i] and start_date <= sched[i] <= end_date for i in (0, 2, 4)):
        print ("Do something here...")
```

It may be useful for other areas of your code to parse your strings into `date()` instances *once*, rather than use strings and convert them each time you need a `datetime.date()` object. For *just this comparison here*, that's not really needed.

Comment: You are a savior! The time saved is tremendous. For the `any()` part, I would have used it but i had to do some filtering in my actual code, i.e. `earliest = [dt for dt in [j["Schedule"][0],j["Schedule"][2],j["Schedule"][4],j["Schedule"][6],j["Schedule"][8]] if dt and not dt.isalnum()]`

Comment: @HenryYik: that's not really an issue; you can still use `any()` for that too; `if any(sched[i] and sched[i].isalnum() and start_date <= sched[i] <= end_date for i in (0, 2, 4))`